# TypeORM Entity in NESTJS - Cannot use import statement outside a module

Tags: nestjs, typeorm

Started new project with 'nest new' command. Works fine until I add entity file to it.

Got following error:

> import { Entity, Column, PrimaryGeneratedColumn } from 'typeorm';
>
> ^^^^^^
>
> SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module

What do I miss?

Adding Entity to Module:

```
import { Module } from '@nestjs/common';
import { BooksController } from './books.controller';
import { BooksService } from './books.service';
import { BookEntity } from './book.entity';
import { TypeOrmModule } from '@nestjs/typeorm';

@Module({
  imports: [TypeOrmModule.forFeature([BookEntity])],
  controllers: [BooksController],
  providers: [BooksService],
})
export class BooksModule {}
```

app.module.ts:

```
import { Module } from '@nestjs/common';
import { AppController } from './app.controller';
import { AppService } from './app.service';
import { TypeOrmModule } from '@nestjs/typeorm';
import { Connection } from 'typeorm';
import { BooksModule } from './books/books.module';

@Module({
  imports: [TypeOrmModule.forRoot()],
  controllers: [AppController],
  providers: [AppService],
})
export class AppModule {}
```

Comment: import { Module } from '@nestjs/common';

Comment: @Preston care to elaborate on what you mean? Do you have to create a module for commonly shared files?

Comment: Are you getting the error from your linter or from a compilation? Where do you have this new file? Is it in your `src` directory? If you're using TypeORM, can you show your `TypeOrmModule` import in the `AppModule`'s `imports` array? There may be something wrong with the configuration we can't see

Comment: updated post with entity import info

Answer (score 216, accepted):

My assumption is that you have a `TypeormModule` configuration with an `entities` property that looks like this:

```
entities: ['src/**/*.entity.{ts,js}']
```

or like

```
entities: ['../**/*.entity.{ts,js}']
```

The error you are getting is because you are attempting to import a `ts` file in a `js` context. So long as you aren't using webpack you can use this instead so that you get the correct files

```
entities: [join(__dirname, '**', '*.entity.{ts,js}')]
```

where `join` is imported from the `path` module. Now `__dirname` will resolve to `src` or `dist` and then find the expected `ts` or `js` file respectively. let me know if there is still an issue going on.

### EDIT 1/10/2020

The above assumes the configuration is done is a javascript compatible file (`.js` or in the `TypeormModule.forRoot()` passed parameters). If you are using an `ormconfig.json` instead, you should use

```json
entities: ["dist/**/*.entity.js"]
```

so that you are using the compiled js files and have no chance to use the ts files in your code.

Or use

```json
autoLoadEntities: true,
```

Comment: But this is a total mess. A typescript ORM that does not accept typescript for the migrations...

Comment: `deno` is the only native typescript code runner. `TypeORM`, while it uses Typescript, still works with `Node` and the JavaScript runtime. Maybe improvements can be made to accept `ts` files and compile them into JavaScript under the hood, then delete them so the end user doesn't see them, but that would need to be brought up as an issue on the TypeORM git repository

Comment: actually full line must be
"entities": ["dist/**/*.entity.js"],
because of json syntax.

Comment: I absolutely agree that having to reach into the transpiled JS for all this mess to work is a joke.

Comment: The Issue [#4283](https://github.com/nestjs/nest/issues/4283#issuecomment-597987321) on Github explains in details why JavaScript should be used to read entities from Dist folder. This is the magic line I changed in `ormconfig.js` in the root folder, you too can try and see. `entities: ['dist/**/*.entity.js']` is the solution.

Comment: This is insane. Aren't we doing Typescript not to have to deal with this garbage?

Answer (score 62):

In the TypeORM documentation, i found a specific section for [Typescript](https://typeorm.io/#/using-cli/if-entities-files-are-in-typescript.).

This section says:

> Install ts-node globally:
>
> ```
> npm install -g ts-node
> ```
>
> Add typeorm command under scripts section in package.json
>
> ```
> "scripts" {
>     ...
>     "typeorm": "ts-node -r tsconfig-paths/register ./node_modules/typeorm/cli.js"    
> }
> ```
>
> Then you may run the command like this:
>
> ```
> npm run typeorm migration:run
> ```
>
> If you need to pass parameter with dash to npm script, you will need
>   to add them after --. For example, if you need to generate, the
>   command is like this:
>
> ```
> npm run typeorm migration:generate -- -n migrationNameHere
> ```

This works with my file config:

```
{
    "type": "postgres",
    "host": "yourhost",
    "port": 5423,
    "username": "username",
    "password": "password",
    "database": "your_db",
    "synchronize": true,
    "entities": [
        "src/modules/**/*.entity.{ts,js}"
    ],
    "migrations": [
        "src/migrations/**/*.{ts,js}"
    ],
    "cli": {
        "entitiesDir": "src/modules",
        "migrationsDir": "src/migrations"
    }
}
```

Then you can run the generate command.

Comment: 22.04.23 I had to run this: `npm run typeorm migration:generate -- migrationNameHere -d ./src/data-source.ts`

Comment: That's really awful. Who has a javascript exclusive tool?

Comment: I get RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded this way. Cant figure out to make it work.

Answer (score 25):

As Jay McDoniel explained in his answer, the problem seems to be the pattern matching of entity files in `ormconfig.json` file: Probably a typescript file (module) is imported from a javascript file (presumably a previously transpiled typescript file).

It should be sufficient to remove an existing `ts` glob pattern in the `ormconfig.json`, so that TypeORM will only load javascript files. The path to the entity files should be relative to the working directory where node is executed.

```
   "entities"   : [
      "dist/entity/**/*.js"
   ],
   "migrations" : [
      "dist/migration/**/*.js"
   ],
   "subscribers": [
      "dist/subscriber/**/*.js"
   ],
```

Comment: The `src` should probably be changed to `dist` as that's where the runnable code is after being transpiled to javascript.

Comment: It took me a while: During runtime, code will be run off the 'dist' (Distribution) folder. And the *.entity.ts file containing the database model, will be translated to .js file by TypeOrm. Hence - entities entry should point to *.entity.js under the 'dist' folder. Thank you all. Save my day.

Answer (score 10):

Defining the entities property in `ormconfig.json` as mentioned in the official documentation resolved this issue for me.

```
// This is your ormconfig.json file

...
"entities": ["dist/**/*.entity{.ts,.js}"]
...
```

Answer (score 8):

I changed in *tsconfig.json* file next:

```
"module": "es6"
```

To:

```
"module": "commonjs",
```

It helps me

Answer (score 7):

Also check out your imports in the entities. Don't `import { SomeClassFromTypeorm } from 'typeorm/browser';` since this can lead to the same error.

It happened to me after my IDE automatically imported the wrong package. Delete `'/browser'` from the import.

Comment: It it helps anyone else, this exact same thing happened to me, on a nestjs & typeorm project. `import { Unique } from 'typeorm/browser';` just needed to be changed to `import { Unique } from 'typeorm';`

Answer (score 5):

This is how I've manage to fix it. With a single configuration file I can run the migrations on application boostrap or using TypeOrm's CLI.

**src/config/ormconfig.ts**

```js
import parseBoolean from '@eturino/ts-parse-boolean';
import { TypeOrmModuleOptions } from '@nestjs/typeorm';
import * as dotenv from 'dotenv';
import { join } from 'path';

dotenv.config();

export = [
  {
    //name: 'default',
    type: 'mssql',
    host: process.env.DEFAULT_DB_HOST,
    username: process.env.DEFAULT_DB_USERNAME,
    password: process.env.DEFAULT_DB_PASSWORD,
    database: process.env.DEFAULT_DB_NAME,
    options: {
      instanceName: process.env.DEFAULT_DB_INSTANCE,
      enableArithAbort: false,
    },
    logging: parseBoolean(process.env.DEFAULT_DB_LOGGING),
    dropSchema: false,
    synchronize: false,
    migrationsRun: parseBoolean(process.env.DEFAULT_DB_RUN_MIGRATIONS),
    migrations: [join(__dirname, '..', 'model/migration/*.{ts,js}')],
    cli: {
      migrationsDir: 'src/model/migration',
    },
    entities: [
      join(__dirname, '..', 'model/entity/default/**/*.entity.{ts,js}'),
    ],
  } as TypeOrmModuleOptions,
  {
    name: 'other',
    type: 'mssql',
    host: process.env.OTHER_DB_HOST,
    username: process.env.OTHER_DB_USERNAME,
    password: process.env.OTHER_DB_PASSWORD,
    database: process.env.OTHER_DB_NAME,
    options: {
      instanceName: process.env.OTHER_DB_INSTANCE,
      enableArithAbort: false,
    },
    logging: parseBoolean(process.env.OTHER_DB_LOGGING),
    dropSchema: false,
    synchronize: false,
    migrationsRun: false,
    entities: [],
  } as TypeOrmModuleOptions,
];
```

**src/app.module.ts**

```js
import configuration from '@config/configuration';
import validationSchema from '@config/validation';
import { Module } from '@nestjs/common';
import { ConfigModule } from '@nestjs/config';
import { TypeOrmModule } from '@nestjs/typeorm';
import { LoggerService } from '@shared/logger/logger.service';
import { UsersModule } from '@user/user.module';
import { AppController } from './app.controller';
import ormconfig = require('./config/ormconfig'); //path mapping doesn't work here

@Module({
  imports: [
    ConfigModule.forRoot({
      cache: true,
      isGlobal: true,
      validationSchema: validationSchema,
      load: [configuration],
    }),
    TypeOrmModule.forRoot(ormconfig[0]), //default
    TypeOrmModule.forRoot(ormconfig[1]), //other db
    LoggerService,
    UsersModule,
  ],
  controllers: [AppController],
})
export class AppModule {}
```

**package.json**

```json
  "scripts": {
    ...
    "typeorm": "ts-node -r tsconfig-paths/register ./node_modules/typeorm/cli.js --config ./src/config/ormconfig.ts",
    "typeorm:migration:generate": "npm run typeorm -- migration:generate -n",
    "typeorm:migration:run": "npm run typeorm -- migration:run"
  },
```

**Project structure**

```
src/
├── app.controller.ts
├── app.module.ts
├── config
│   ├── configuration.ts
│   ├── ormconfig.ts
│   └── validation.ts
├── main.ts
├── model
│   ├── entity
│   ├── migration
│   └── repository
├── route
│   └── user
└── shared
    └── logger
```

Comment: I had to update `migrations` to match your syntax

Answer (score 4):

I was using Node.js with Typescript and TypeORM when I faced this issue. Configuring in ormconfig.json file worked for me.

```
entities: ['dist/**/*.entity.js']
```

My full code of ormconfig.json file:

```
{
  "type": "mysql",
  "host": "localhost",
  "port": 3306,
  "username": "xxxxxxxx",
  "password": "xxxxxxxx",
  "database": "typescript_orm",
  "synchronize": true,
  "logging": false,
  "migrationTableName": "migrations",
  "entities": [
    "dist/**/*.entity.js"
  ],
  "migrations": [
    "src/migration/**/*.{ts, js}"
  ],
  "suscribers": [
    "src/suscriber/**/*.{ts, js}"
  ],
  "cli": {
    "entitiesDir": "src/model",
    "migrationDir": "src/migration",
    "suscribersDir": "src/suscriber"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

In line with other people's comments - it does in fact seem silly to have to depend on generated code for this to work.  I do not take credit for this solution as it's someone else's repository, but it does in fact allow full Typescript only migrations.  It relies on the `.env` file Typeorm values instead of `ormconfig.json` although I'm sure it could be translated. I found it instrumental in helping me remove the dependency on `.js` files.

Here is the repo:
https://github.com/mthomps4/next-now-test/tree/next-typeorm-example

**Explanation as to how it's working:**

Aside from your usual .env or ormconfig.json file with the proper localhost db connection in it, you also need to specify the following properly in ormconfig.json or .env file

```
TYPEORM_ENTITIES="entities/*.ts"
TYPEORM_MIGRATIONS="migrations/*.ts"
TYPEORM_ENTITIES_DIR="entities"
TYPEORM_MIGRATIONS_DIR="migrations"
```

Notice the entities and migrations globs only have `*.ts`.  The other very important piece is how your npm scripts are setup to run with `ts-node`.

You need an extended tsconfig that has the following in it somewhere:

```
{
  "extends": "./tsconfig.json",
  "compilerOptions": {
    "module": "commonjs"
  }
}
```

This is what allows ts-node to "pick up" the .ts files properly while generating a migration.

This npm script (the DOTENV part is only if using .env files instead of `ormconfig.json`) specifies to use that `tsconfig.json`

```
 "local": "DOTENV_CONFIG_PATH=./.env ts-node -P ./tsconfig.yarn.json -r dotenv/config"
```

Which is leveraged as a "pre-cursor" script to this:

```
"typeorm:local": "yarn local ./node_modules/typeorm/cli.js"
```

I'm not 100% sure all of that is necessary (you may could do it all inline) but it works for me.  Basically this says "invoke the typrorm cli in the context of ts-node with a specific .env file and a specific tsconfig."  You may be able to skip those configurations in some cases.

Lastly, this script now works:

```
"g:migration": "yarn typeorm:local migration:generate -n"
```

So by running:

```
npm run g:migration -- User
```

You will get your automatically generated migration file based on your current changed entities!

So 3 nested npm scripts later, we have a very specific way to run the "generate" migration conmmand with all the proper configuration to use *only* TS files.  Yay - no wonder some people still rail against typescript but thankfully this does work and the example repo above has it all preconfigured if you want to try it out to see how it "just works".

Comment: Thanks for this; useful!

Answer (score 3):

Surprised about these almost kinda hacky solutions, particularely at the accepted one...

**You should never import anything from a dist folder inside your ts source code!**

If the answered assumption is true, and you do this:

```
entities: ['src/**/*.entity.{ts,js}']
```

then, why don't you rather **DO THIS**:

```
import { Answer } from './entities/answer/answer.entity';

entities: [Answer]
```

This way you would you use your ts code (correctly) and the builded js code would get provided to the TypeOrmModule in runtime.

Answer (score 3):

check your TypeOrmModule's entities

```
TypeOrmModule.forRoot({
  type: 'postgres',
  host: 'localhost',
  port: 5432,
  username: 'postgres',
  password: '#GoHomeGota',
  database: 'quiz',
  **entities: ["dist/**/*.entity{.ts,.js}"],**
  synchronize: true,
}),
```

Answer (score 3):

The alternative I found for this is having two orm config files
namely orm-config.ts and cli-orm-config.ts (You can name them whatever)

```
//content of cli-orm-config.ts

import { DataSource, DataSourceOptions } from "typeorm"
import 'dotenv/config'

export const cliOrmConfig: DataSourceOptions = {
    type: 'postgres',
    host: process.env.DATABASE_HOST,
    port: (process.env.PG_DATABASE_PORT as any) as number,
    username: process.env.PG_DATABASE_USER,
    password: process.env.PG_DATABASE_PASSWORD,
    database: process.env.DATABASE_NAME,
    entities: ["src/**/*/*.entity{.ts,.js}"],
    migrations: ["src/**/*/*-Migration{.ts,.js}"]
}

const datasource = new DataSource(cliOrmConfig)

export default  datasource
```

```
//content of orm-config.ts, this is the one I use in nest TypeOrmModule.forRoot(ormConfig)

import { DataSource, DataSourceOptions } from 'typeorm';
import 'dotenv/config'


export const ormConfig: DataSourceOptions = {
    type: 'postgres',
    host: process.env.DATABASE_HOST,
    port: (process.env.PG_DATABASE_PORT as any) as number,
    username: process.env.PG_DATABASE_USER,
    password: process.env.PG_DATABASE_PASSWORD,
    database: process.env.DATABASE_NAME,
    entities: ["dist/src/**/*/*.entity{.ts,.js}"]
}

const datasource = new DataSource(ormConfig)

export default  datasource
```

```
// My package.json relevant scripts section

"typeorm": "ts-node ./node_modules/typeorm/cli -d ./src/db/cli-orm-config.ts",
"nest:migration:generate": "npm run typeorm migration:generate ./src/db/migrations/Migration",
"nest:migration:run": "npm run typeorm migration:run"
```

I think as far as TypeOrm is concerned, the migration, cli parts should be teared apart from models loading and other stuffs; hence the seperation of the orm configs file for both.

Hope it helps somebody

Answer (score 2):

Actually, typeorm was designed to work with javascript by default.

To run the migrations with typescript, you must tell typeorm to do it.

Just put in your package.json, in the scripts part this line below:

```
"typeorm": "ts-node-dev ./node_modules/typeorm/cli.js"
```

and then, try to migrate again:

```
yarn typeorm migration:run
```

Comment: doesnt work. "Missing required argument: dataSource"

Answer (score 2):

I think a better solution, than the accepted one, is to create a alias in your shell of choice, that uses `ts-node` inside `node_modules`.

Note: I'm doing this in bash, with OhMyZsh, so your configuration might be totally different.

**1: Open shell configuration**

Open shell configuration1

```sh
nano ~/.zshrc
```

**2: Find the place where other aliases are defined and add a new alias**

```sh
alias typeorm="ts-node ./node_modules/typeorm/cli.js"
```

**3: Close and save**

Press <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>X</kbd> to request nano to exit and press <kbd>Y</kbd> to confirm to save the configuration.

**4: Apply the new configuration**

```sh
. ~/.zshrc
```

**5: Close terminal and open it again**

You can now go to your project root and type "typeorm" which will use ts-node in conjunction with the typeorm-cli from your node_modules.

Answer (score 2):

I ran into this error trying to run `typeorm migration:generate` from a project created with the TypeORM starter kit (`npx typeorm init`). The issue came down to this bit that it inserted into `package.json`:

```json
   "scripts": {
      "typeorm": "typeorm-ts-node-commonjs"
   }
```

Change that to:

```json
   "scripts": {
      "typeorm": "typeorm-ts-node-esm"
   }
```

And you should be good to go:

```
npm run -- typeorm migration:generate --dataSource path/to/data-source.ts NameOfMigration
```

Comment: Thank you! Struggled a lot with this

Answer (score 2):

I Upgraded NestJs to 9.2.0 and typeorm to 0.3.10
And i got a probleme when runing a new migration
But i Found out the solution and that works for me:

in the previous Version (nest 7 typeorm 0.2) i used this command :

```
npx ts-node ./node_modules/.bin/typeorm migration:generate -n MigrationName -d src/migrations
```

and after updating i used this command and it workd for me:

```
npx ts-node ./node_modules/.bin/typeorm migration:generate src/migration/MigrationName -d ormconfig.js
```

when generate migration we need to set the path of the new migrationFile migration:generate

-d means directory of migration => -d src/migration in **typeorm 0.2**

-d means dataSource (config) => -d ormconfig in **typeorm 0.3**

Answer (score 1):

You need to have a something.module.ts for every section of your app.  It works like Angular.  This is setup with GraphQL resolvers and service. REST is a bit different with a controller.  Each module will probably have an entity and if GraphQL, projects.schema.graphql.

projects.module.ts

```
import { Module } from '@nestjs/common';
import { TypeOrmModule } from '@nestjs/typeorm';
import { ProjectsService } from './projects.service';
import { Projects } from './projects.entity';

import { ProjectsResolvers } from './projects.resolvers';

@Module({
  imports: [
    TypeOrmModule.forFeature([Projects])],
  providers: [
    ProjectsService,
    ProjectsResolvers
  ],

})

export class ProjectsModule {}
```

Comment: Excellent. So does that mean you can ever have a base entity shared across multiple modules or would that base entity have to be part of a commons module of sorts?

Comment: I think i've already imported entity to module. Please take a look at updated post

Comment: Sorry Anton, I'm traveling on vacation now and can't help you until January.  I would have to look at my old REST modules and I don't have them with me.

Comment: Anton, if you have already solved this then please post your solution to SO.

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me - no changes needed to your `ormconfig.js`. Run from your root directory where the `node_modules` are:

```
ts-node ./node_modules/typeorm/cli.js  migration:generate -n <MirgrationName> -c <ConnectionType>
```

Example:

```
ts-node ./node_modules/typeorm/cli.js  migration:create -n AuthorHasMultipleBooks -c development
```

Comment: not working "Not enough non-option arguments: got 0, need at least 1"

Answer (score 1):

Configuration to support migrations:

```js
// FILE: src/config/ormconfig.ts

const connectionOptions: ConnectionOptions = {
  
  // Other configs here

  // My ormconfig isn't in root folder
  entities: [`${__dirname}/../**/*.entity.{ts,js}`],
  synchronize: false,
  dropSchema: false,
  migrationsRun: false,
  migrations: [getMigrationDirectory()],
  cli: {
    migrationsDir: 'src/migrations',
  }
}

function getMigrationDirectory() {
    const directory = process.env.NODE_ENV === 'migration' ? 'src' : `${__dirname}`;
    return `${directory}/migrations/**/*{.ts,.js}`;
}

export = connectionOptions;
```

```json
// FILE package.json

{
  // Other configs here

  "scripts": {
    "typeorm": "NODE_ENV=migration ts-node -r tsconfig-paths/register ./node_modules/typeorm/cli.js --config src/config/database.ts",
    "typeorm:migrate": "npm run typeorm migration:generate -- -n",
    "typeorm:run": "npm run typeorm migration:run",
    "typeorm:revert": "npm run typeorm migration:revert"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I have encountered the same problem. The only difference is that my project uses .env file instead of ormconfig.json

This is what my .env file configuration looks like.

```
TYPEORM_ENTITIES = src/modules/*.entity.ts
TYPEORM_MIGRATIONS = src/migrations/*.entity.ts
TYPEORM_MIGRATIONS_RUN = src/migrations
TYPEORM_ENTITIES_DIR = src/modules
TYPEORM_MIGRATIONS_DIR = src/migrations
```

And run by using command

```
nest start
```

The problem appears to be that TypeORM does not accept entities in the form of typescript files.

There are two approaches that can be used to solve this problem.

1. Use `node-ts` instead of `nest start` solved the problem without modifying the path of the entities file. From my understanding, node-ts will process the typescript file in the src folder without issue.
2. Change the entity and migration file paths to point to the compiled js file in the dist folder instead.

   ```
    TYPEORM_ENTITIES = dist/modules/*.entity.js
    TYPEORM_MIGRATIONS = dist/migrations/*.entity.js
    TYPEORM_MIGRATIONS_RUN = dist/migrations
    TYPEORM_ENTITIES_DIR = dist/modules
    TYPEORM_MIGRATIONS_DIR = dist/migrations
   ```

   with this approach, I can use `nest start` without any problem.

Answer (score 1):

I solved the problem!

1. Create `pm2.config.js` file in root with below codes:

   ```
    module.exports = {
      apps: [
        {
          name: "app",
          script: "./build/index.js",
        },
      ],
    };
   ```
2. Change entity path in `ormconfig.js`

   ```
   {
      "type": "postgres",
      "host": "localhost",
      "port": 5432,
      "username": "postgres",
      "password": "password",
      "database": "db_name",
      "synchronize": false,
      "logging": true,
      "entities": [
         "../src/entity/**/*.ts",  ===>>> this line is important
         "./build/entity/**/*.js"
      ],
      "migrations": [
         "../src/migration/**/*.ts",===>>> this line is important
         "./build/migration/**/*.js"
      ],
      "subscribers": [
         "../src/subscriber/**/*.ts",===>>> this line is important
         "./build/subscriber/**/*.js"
      ],
      "cli": {
         "entitiesDir": "src/entity",
         "migrationsDir": "src/migration",
         "subscribersDir": "src/subscriber"
      }
   }
   ```
3. `tsconfig.json` with below code:

   ```
   {
      "compilerOptions": {
         "lib": [
            "es5",
            "es6"
         ],
         "target": "es5",
         "module": "commonjs",
         "moduleResolution": "node",
         "outDir": "./build",
         "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
         "experimentalDecorators": true,
         "sourceMap": true,
         "esModuleInterop": true
      }
   }
   ```
4. Run below command for production:

   ```
   tsc  =>> This command generate "build" folder
   ```
5. Run below command for run node app in `pm2`:

   ```
   tsc && pm2 start pm2.config.js
   ```

Now after 2 days with this solution my app with node express & typeorm is worked!
Also my app are working on linux & nginx with pm2.

Comment: I used this solution only for production. for development I change "../src/entity/**/*.ts" to "src/entity/**/*.ts" and then run "nodemon --exec ts-node ./src/index.ts" and it works

Answer (score 1):

I used this solution only for production.
for development I change `"../src/entity/**/*.ts"` to `"src/entity/**/*.ts"` and then run this command: `"nodemon --exec ts-node ./src/index.ts"` and it works –

Answer (score 1):

The accepted answer here (https://stackoverflow.com/a/59607836/2040160) was help me generate and run the migrations, but not to run the NestJS project. I got the same error as the author when I `npm run start:dev`.

What worked for me, is to just generate the migrations file in vanilla JavaScript.
My `ormconfig,json` file:

```
{ 
  "type": "cockroachdb",
  "host": "localhost",
  "port": 26257,
  "username": "root",
  "password": "",
  "database": "test",
  "entities": ["dist/**/*.entity{.ts,.js}"],
  "migrations": ["migration/*.js"],
  "synchronize": false,
  "cli": {
    "migrationsDir": "migration"
  }
}
```

The script in `package.json`:

```
"typeorm": "node --require ts-node/register ./node_modules/typeorm/cli.js"
```

And the command I use to generate the migrations:

```
npm run typeorm migration:generate -- -o -n init
```

The `-o` flag will output the migrations in vanilla JavaScript.

Comment: That is not a solution. You just created a workaround and pretend that the problem is fixed.

Comment: I don't pretend that the problem is fixed, I just wanted to help and add the workaround that worked for me. Maybe it'll shad more light on the issue and help someone figure out a solution.

Answer (score 0):

If you are writing in typescript and use `tsc` to create a dist folder with translated js files in it, then you probably have my issue and it will get fixed here.

As it is mentioned here in the [docs](https://typeorm.io/#undefined/loading-all-entities-from-the-directory) if you use `nodemon server.js`, then you will hit the entities from js perspective and it will not recognize import as it is ts and es6 related. However if you want to import entities from ts files, you should run `ts-node server.ts`!

Personally I believe the former `node server.js` is a safer one to do as it is closer to the real case application.

!!! HOWEVER !!! Be very careful as you have to delete the dist folder and rebuild it if you change an entity's name, otherwise it will throw an error or work unexpectedly.
The error happens because the `tsc` will try to translate the changed and created ts files and leave the deleted files so it can run faster!

I hope it helped as it will definitely help me in the future as I am almost certain I will forget about it again!

Answer (score 0):

The error is on your ormconfig.json file. check where is your code searching for the entities, migrations, subscribers. In a dev, test environment it will search for them in your src/entities src/migrations src/subscribers. But in a production environment, if you leave it as it is, it will still search in the same path instead of your build path dist/src/entities etc.... ;)

Answer (score 0):

I spent so much time in this mini compilation hell :)
Just use the autoLoadEntities option in https://docs.nestjs.com/techniques/database

v useful!!

Answer (score 0):

For me, changing module in my `tsconfig.ts`
from

```
"module": "esnext"
```

To:

```
"module": "commonjs",
```

Did the job.

Answer (score 0):

In my scenario, the import statement problem persisted despite attempting various troubleshooting steps. Initially, my Node.js environment was set to version 20. However, after exhausting multiple solutions without success, I switched to Node.js version 18 and this issue was resolved.

Answer (score -2):

npm run typeorm migration:generate  -- -n translationLength

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).