# Typeorm don't use ormconfig.json file

Tags: nestjs, typeorm

i'am configuring nestjs ormconfig.json but typeorm don't connect to mysql 8 database, it display this in cli

```
[Nest] 13324   - 2020-01-14 4:15:32   [NestFactory] Starting Nest application...
[Nest] 13324   - 2020-01-14 4:15:32   [InstanceLoader] AppModule dependencies initialized +513ms
[Nest] 13324   - 2020-01-14 4:15:32   [InstanceLoader] TypeOrmModule dependencies initialized +5ms
[Nest] 13324   - 2020-01-14 4:15:36   [TypeOrmModule] Unable to connect to the database. Retrying (1)... +4061ms
Error: Cannot find module 'src/user/user.entity'
Require stack:
- C:\Users\redwolf\Labs\projets-pro\kissing-api\src\appel\appel.entity.ts
- C:\Users\redwolf\Labs\projets-pro\kissing-api\node_modules\typeorm\platform\PlatformTools.js
- C:\Users\redwolf\Labs\projets-pro\kissing-api\node_modules\typeorm\driver\sqlserver\SqlServerDriver.js
- C:\Users\redwolf\Labs\projets-pro\kissing-api\node_modules\typeorm\migration\MigrationExecutor.js
- C:\Users\redwolf\Labs\projets-pro\kissing-api\node_modules\typeorm\connection\Connection.js
- C:\Users\redwolf\Labs\projets-pro\kissing-api\node_modules\typeorm\connection\ConnectionManager.js
- C:\Users\redwolf\Labs\projets-pro\kissing-api\node_modules\typeorm\index.js
- C:\Users\redwolf\Labs\projets-pro\kissing-api\node_modules\@nestjs\typeorm\dist\common\typeorm.utils.js
- C:\Users\redwolf\Labs\projets-pro\kissing-api\node_modules\@nestjs\typeorm\dist\common\typeorm.decorators.js
- C:\Users\redwolf\Labs\projets-pro\kissing-api\node_modules\@nestjs\typeorm\dist\common\index.js
- C:\Users\redwolf\Labs\projets-pro\kissing-api\node_modules\@nestjs\typeorm\dist\index.js
- C:\Users\redwolf\Labs\projets-pro\kissing-api\node_modules\@nestjs\typeorm\index.js
- C:\Users\redwolf\Labs\projets-pro\kissing-api\src\app.module.ts
- C:\Users\redwolf\Labs\projets-pro\kissing-api\src\main.ts
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:797:15)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:690:27)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:852:19)
    at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:74:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\redwolf\Labs\projets-pro\kissing-api\src\appel\appel.entity.ts:3:1)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:959:30)
    at Module.m._compile (C:\Users\redwolf\Labs\projets-pro\kissing-api\node_modules\ts-node\src\index.ts:806:23)
    at Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:995:10)
    at Object.require.extensions.<computed> [as .ts] (C:\Users\redwolf\Labs\projets-pro\kissing-api\node_modules\ts-node\src\index.ts:809:12)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:815:32)
```

all entities are in src folder but the console still say the're not

and this is my code

```
app.module.ts

import { Module } from '@nestjs/common';
import { TypeOrmModule } from '@nestjs/typeorm';

@Module({
  imports: [
      TypeOrmModule.forRoot(),
  ],
})
export class AppModule {}
```

ormconfig.json

```
{
  "type": "mysql",
  "host": "localhost",
  "port": 3306,
  "username": "admin",
  "password": "",
  "database": "kissing_db",
  "synchronize": true,
  "logging": true,
  "entities": [
    "src/**/*.entity.ts",
    "dist/**/*.entity.js"
  ],
  "migrationsTableName": "migration",
  "migrations": [
    "src/migration/*.ts"
  ],
  "cli": {
    "migrationsDir": "./src/migration"
  },
  "ssl": false
}
```

I don't post it with password for security reason hope you'll understand.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When compiling from Typescript to JavaScript, your code gets moved from `.ts` files in the `src` directory to `.js` files in the `dist` directory. From there, Node still tries to resolve the paths given from your base directory (once in `dist` the base is `dist`), so it tries to resolve `dist/src/user/user.entity` which obviously doesn't exist. Instead, you should remove the `src/**/*.entity.ts` from the `ormconfig.json` so that it will only look for compiled JavaScript files.

[There's a bit more information here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59435293/typeorm-entity-in-nestjs-cannot-use-import-statement-outside-a-module).

Comment: but how do i do for development mode?

Comment: I've change remove the ```src/**/*.entity.ts``` from my ```ormconfig.json``` file but i still have this error in cli ```Entity metadata for CaracteristiqueUser#photos was not found. Check if you specified a correct entity object and if it's connected in the connection options```

Comment: that's my package.json start scripts ```"scripts": {
    "start": "tsc-watch -r tsconfig-paths/register src/main.ts",
    "start:dev": "nodemon",
    "start:debug": "nest start --debug --watch",
    "start:prod": "node dist/main",
  },```

Comment: With your `nodemon`, are you also compiling the ts or are you using `ts-node`?

Comment: i use a nodemon.json file ```{
    "watch": ["src"],
    "ext": "ts",
    "ignore": ["src/**/*.spec.ts"],
    "exec": "node --inspect=127.0.0.1:9223 -r ts-node/register -- src/main.ts",
    "env": {}
}```

Comment: Ah, so it is using `ts-node`. I would suggest trying to move towards `tsc-watch` and `tsc` in general as it will make configurations easier. Otherwise, you would need to change the `ormconfig.json` each time you want to move between dev and prod. It's super annoying, I know. The other option is to use `ormconfig.js` instead and use `__dirname` to dynamically change between `dist` and `src`

Answer (score 0):

I think i've found a solution i've just create a `ormconfig.js` withouth `entities` field like this

```
module.exports = {
   "type": "mysql",
   "host": "localhost",
   "port": 3306,
   "username": "admin",
   "password": "",
   "database": "kissing_db",
   "synchronize": true,
   "logging": true,
};
```

and edit my `package.json` start scripts with `ts-node`, it seem like ts-node automatically find entity files.