# "Cannot use import statement outside a module" in typeorm migration when run nestjs app

Tags: nestjs, typeorm

I have created the nestjs app. In the root app folder I have these subfolders:

- dist
- migration
- src
- test

The migration folder contains typeorm migrations.
When run application with *npm run start:dev* I have this error:

```
import {MigrationInterface, QueryRunner} from "typeorm";
^^^^^^

SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:891:18)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:991:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:811:32)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:723:14)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:848:19)
    at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:74:18)
    at Function.PlatformTools.load (C:\Users\dakru1\Documents\employo\employo-api\node_modules\typeorm\platform\PlatformTools.js:114:28)
    at C:\Users\dakru1\Documents\employo\employo-api\node_modules\typeorm\util\DirectoryExportedClassesLoader.js:39:69
    at Array.map (<anonymous>)
    at Object.importClassesFromDirectories (C:\Users\dakru1\Documents\employo\employo-api\node_modules\typeorm\util\DirectoryExportedClassesLoader.js:39:10)
```

I understand the error message and I know how to fix it when it relates to application's code.

However, my problem is that this error come from typeorm migration file: `[app-root-folder]\migration\1587067680466-Init.ts` which shouldn't be used when application runs.

Why nestjs uses migration files. How can I ignore migration folder when running nestjs app?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [TypeORM Entity in NESTJS - Cannot use import statement outside a module](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59435293/typeorm-entity-in-nestjs-cannot-use-import-statement-outside-a-module)

Answer (score 11):

to solve it just put the following code on your "scripts" at package.json:

```
"typeorm": "ts-node-dev ./node_modules/typeorm/cli.js",
```

After that you'll be able to run your typeorm migration:run :)

Comment: If you use `npx typeorm init` as described in (https://typeorm.io/#quick-start), typeorm adds 
```
"typeorm": "typeorm-ts-node-commonjs"
```
in your package.js. To run migration, don't forget to add -- on your npm command line to pass arguments:

`npm run typeorm migration:generate -- -d src/data-source.ts migrations/mig`

Comment: @VincentGODIN thank you. I have been looking to resolve this issue for a while and adding -- and using npm run typeorm worked. I kept my as typeorm:"typeorm-ts-node-commonjs"

Answer (score 11):

I found the solution:

This happends to me because I was using **Nest** and when you run the command `nest start`, under the hood, **Nest** executes node and tsc and node commands and because of that you need your files to be in JavaScript format. So, as the migrations are generated in Typescript... the statement import gives the error because is only for TypeScript.

The only thing i did to solve it is this:

```
migrations: ["dist/migrations/*.js"],
```

This is telling TypeOrm that search for the migration in the `dist` directory where all the JavaScript code was compiled previously.

Of course in my `tsconfig.json` file the output dir is pointing to `dist`.

```
"outDir": "./dist",
```

Comment: This works. I don't know why but it works.

Comment: The only thing I did different was point this to my actual `./src/migrations/*.ts` folder. Who knew that would be a bad idea…

Answer (score 3):

I had the same issue. I did the following as a workaround:

1. Set your ormconfig.json to look for migrations files with only `js` suffix:
   `"migrations": ["migrations/*.js"]`,
2. Install typescript globally: `npm install -g typescript`
3. After generating your migration, transpile typescript files to javascript files with typescript command:
   `tsc migrations/migration-file.ts`
4. Run your migration: `npm run typeorm migration:run`
5. You can now run your application: `npm run start:dev`

Comment: This is the top answer but don't do this. Check out Tiago's answer.

Comment: @Gus could you elaborate more on why we shouldn't do this ?

Comment: There are many things wrong with it: It breaks on TypeScript (because of the `.ts` -> `.js` change), requires installing a package globally, requires more steps, etc.

Comment: This works for me, it's not an elegant/automated solution but helps you to address the issue.

Answer (score 2):

For TypeORM v0.3.0 or higher, **glob patterns** in `migrations` are [DEPRECATED](https://typeorm.io/changelog#deprecations). It is recommended to directly include the migration classes.

> entities, migrations, subscribers options inside DataSourceOptions accepting string directories support is deprecated. You'll be only able to pass entity references in the future versions.

```js
import { DataSource, DataSourceOptions } from 'typeorm';
import { CreateUser1669370712331 } from '../../migrations/1669370712331-CreateUser';
import { UserModify1669457039074 } from '../../migrations/1669457039074-UserModify';
import { User } from '../users/entities/user.entity';

export const config: DataSourceOptions = {
  type: 'sqlite',
  database: 'db/database.sqlite',
  logging: true,
  synchronize: false,
  entities: [User],
  migrations: [CreateUser1669370712331, UserModify1669457039074],
};
```

Comment: This is hard to maintain, in my project I have more than 450 migrations

Answer (score 1):

[Changelog's Depracations Section of 0.3.0](https://github.com/typeorm/typeorm/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md#deprecations)

> entities, migrations, subscribers options inside DataSourceOptions accepting string directories support is deprecated. You'll be only able to pass entity references in the future versions.

But actually when I used glob pattern I was getting the same error as you. And this error is actually caused by trying to run ts content in the js environment. The main reason is that we use the glob pattern to import files with ts extension to `DataSourceOptions`. (I assume your situation is like this as you should not receive such an error if you are passing entity references directly)

Solution:

#### Step - 1

Use glob pattern to get output js files in your DataSourceOptions

```
  migrations: ['dist/db/migrations/*.js'],
```

#### Step - 2

Add `npm run build` to the beginning of the `typeorm` script in package.json. (In this way, we will make sure that our output js exists.)

```
    "typeorm": "npm run build && typeorm-ts-node-esm -d dist/db/data-source.js",
```

#### Optional

I don't know if you need it, but actually, while I was solving problems related to migrations, the application would not start or vice versa, or an unrelated place would get corrupted. Thinking that maybe it will prevent you from having to deal with them, I'm sharing other scripts.

```
"migration:generate": "npm run typeorm -- migration:generate",
"migration:run": "npm run typeorm -- migration:run",
"migration:revert": "npm run typeorm -- migration:revert"
```

Answer (score 0):

I know this question is old, but I just came across it because I had the same problem.  I was able to solve it by adding "migration/**/*.ts" to the "exclude" array in the /tsconfig.build.json file like so:

```
{
  "extends": "./tsconfig.json",
  "exclude": ["node_modules", "test", "dist", "**/*spec.ts", "migration/**/*.ts"]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The same issue here, and in my case the root cause was a wrong migrations path in the connection configuration, like this;

```
const databaseConfig: ConnectionOptions = {
  name: 'default',
  type: 'postgres',
  host: process.env.TYPEORM_HOST || '',
  port: Number(process.env.TYPEORM_PORT),
  username: process.env.TYPEORM_USERNAME || '',
  password: process.env.TYPEORM_PASSWORD || '',
  database: process.env.TYPEORM_DATABASE || '',
  logging: false,
  synchronize: false,
  entities: [],
  migrations: ['src/migrations/*.ts'],
};
```

**Instead, I have changed it to**

```
const migrationPaths: string[] = process.env.TYPEORM_USE_CLI === 'true' ? ['src/migrations/*{.ts,.js}'] : [];

const databaseConfig: ConnectionOptions = {
  name: 'default',
  type: 'postgres',
  host: process.env.TYPEORM_HOST || '',
  port: Number(process.env.TYPEORM_PORT),
  username: process.env.TYPEORM_USERNAME || '',
  password: process.env.TYPEORM_PASSWORD || '',
  database: process.env.TYPEORM_DATABASE || '',
  logging: false,
  synchronize: false,
  entities: [],
  migrations: migrationPaths,
};
```

another test you can try to see if the problem is really with migration is to move the migration filter out of src.