# Cannot use import statement outside a module in nestjs using typeorm

Tags: nestjs, database-migration, typeorm

while a execute `npm run typeorm migration:generate -- -n migrationNameHere` all is working good and then when i execute `npm run typeorm migration:run` all the migration are ok in the database , but when i execute `npm run start:dev` i get an error :

[This is the error i get](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IQuXA.png)

the is the tree of my folders:

[The structure of my folders](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NDaqX.png)

this is my ormconfig.json file:

```
{
"type": "mysql",
"host": "localhost",
"port": 3306,
"username": "root",
"password": "",
"database": "tpicoxxxxx",
"entities": ["dist/**/*.entity{.ts,.js}"],
"migrationsTableName": "migrations_table",
"migrations": ["src/databasesssx/migrations/*{.ts,.js}"],
"cli": {
    "migrationsDir": "src/databasesssx/migrations"
}
```

}

in the package.json file i have the following line in scripts section:

```
 "typeorm": "ts-node-dev ./node_modules/typeorm/cli.js"
```

i am using typeorm , mysql2

i am using mac big sur.

i thought maybe the problem maybe is because databasesssx folder is outside of src and then i move inside src folder but the problem did not go.

this is my script in registro module:

```
import { Module } from '@nestjs/common';
 import { TypeOrmModule } from '@nestjs/typeorm';
import { Administrador } from './administrador/entities/administrador.entity';
import { RegistroControllerController } from './registro-controller/registro- 
controller.controller';
import { ServiceRegistroService } from './service-registro/service-registro.service';

 @Module({

  imports : [
    TypeOrmModule.forFeature([Administrador]),
  ],

 providers: [ServiceRegistroService],

  controllers: [RegistroControllerController]  

 })
  export class RegistroModule {}
```

and this is the script in app.module

```
import { Module } from '@nestjs/common';
import { TypeOrmModule } from '@nestjs/typeorm';
import { AppController } from './app.controller';
 import { AppService } from './app.service';
import { RegistroModule } from './registro/registro.module';

   @Module({
  imports: [RegistroModule  ,TypeOrmModule.forRoot()],
   controllers: [AppController],
   providers: [AppService],
   })
   export class AppModule {}
```

then i tried following the next solution in this site of stack overflow : [Similar Problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61259812/cannot-use-import-statement-outside-a-module-in-typeorm-migration-when-run-nes/65063913#65063913)

but the problem is still there.

By the way i am using xammp in mac with phpmyadmin.

Thank you so much.

Comment: show us your `start:dev` npm-script

Comment: what if you change `dist` to `src` of your ormconfig

Comment: Hello @MicaelLevi this is the script: `start:dev: nest start --watch` is inside package.json.

Comment: @MicaelLevi if i change dist to src the migrations and all works but the main problem is still there.

Answer (score 0):

> `"migrations": ["src/databasesssx/migrations/*{.ts,.js}"],`

This tells TypeORM where the migrations exist, which is fine, until you realize that TypeORM will read for the migrations not only at the time of running migrations, but also at time of starting the application. So now, while running `nest start --watch` which essentially runs `node` under the hood, the JavaScript engine is importing a Typescript file from `src/migrations` and is causing an error. If possible, I would separate out the runtime config from the CLI config to ensure this kind of thing cannot happen

Comment: Thank you so much @Jay McDoniel, well i am going to invesstigate how to do that configuration :). thank you

Comment: i dont know how to separate it how can i do it? please

Comment: You can make two configuration files, as one option.