# how to correctly configure entities on ormconfig.json file from typeorm in nestjs?

Tags: nestjs, typeorm

I'm trying to use TypeORM with Nestjs and I have troubles configuring the routes of the entities.

This is my project structure:

[root folder > src > modules > courses > entities > course.entity.ts](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gugE7.png)

My ormconfig.json looks like this:

```
{
  "type": "mysql",
  "host": "localhost",
  "port": 3306,
  "username": "root",
  "password": "",
  "database": "test",
  "entities": ["src/modules/**/entities/*.entity{.ts,.js}"],
  "synchronize": true
}
```

and my app.module.ts looks like this:

```
import { Module } from '@nestjs/common';
import { TypeOrmModule } from "@nestjs/typeorm";
import { CoursesModule } from './modules/courses/courses.module';
import { SchoolsModule } from './modules/schools/schools.module';

@Module({
  imports: [
    TypeOrmModule.forRoot(),
    CoursesModule,
    SchoolsModule
  ],
  controllers: [],
  providers: [],
})
export class AppModule { }
```

but when I run the project with the command **npm run start:dev** got this error:

```
EntityMetadataNotFound: No metadata for "Course" was found.
    at new EntityMetadataNotFoundError (C:\Users\x_jem\Documents\Projects\www\titanx-e-learning-api\node_modules\typeorm\error\EntityMetadataNotFoundError.js:10:28)
    at Connection.getMetadata (C:\Users\x_jem\Documents\Projects\www\titanx-e-learning-api\node_modules\typeorm\connection\Connection.js:336:19)
    at EntityManager.getCustomRepository (C:\Users\x_jem\Documents\Projects\www\titanx-e-learning-api\node_modules\typeorm\entity-manager\EntityManager.js:702:84)
    at Connection.getCustomRepository (C:\Users\x_jem\Documents\Projects\www\titanx-e-learning-api\node_modules\typeorm\connection\Connection.js:365:29)
    at InstanceWrapper.useFactory [as metatype] (C:\Users\x_jem\Documents\Projects\www\titanx-e-learning-api\node_modules\@nestjs\typeorm\dist\typeorm.providers.js:11:35)
    at Injector.instantiateClass (C:\Users\x_jem\Documents\Projects\www\titanx-e-learning-api\node_modules\@nestjs\core\injector\injector.js:292:55)
    at callback (C:\Users\x_jem\Documents\Projects\www\titanx-e-learning-api\node_modules\@nestjs\core\injector\injector.js:76:41)
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:93:5)
    at async Injector.resolveConstructorParams (C:\Users\x_jem\Documents\Projects\www\titanx-e-learning-api\node_modules\@nestjs\core\injector\injector.js:117:24)
    at async Injector.loadInstance (C:\Users\x_jem\Documents\Projects\www\titanx-e-learning-api\node_modules\@nestjs\core\injector\injector.js:80:9)
```

I tried to pass the entities on the forRoot method of the app.module.ts file like this:

```
import { Module } from '@nestjs/common';
import { TypeOrmModule } from "@nestjs/typeorm";
import { CoursesModule } from './modules/courses/courses.module';
import { Course } from './modules/courses/entities/course.entity';

@Module({
  imports: [
    TypeOrmModule.forRoot({
      "type": "mysql",
      "host": "localhost",
      "port": 3306,
      "username": "root",
      "password": "",
      "database": "test",
      "entities": [Course],
      "synchronize": true
    }),
    CoursesModule
  ],
  controllers: [],
  providers: [],
})
export class AppModule { }
```

and all works, but I know that's not the way that I have to do this on the production server. So anyone can help me to find what's going on and how to solve it?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [TypeORM Entity in NESTJS - Cannot use import statement outside a module](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59435293/typeorm-entity-in-nestjs-cannot-use-import-statement-outside-a-module)

Comment: Idk if the problem was the same (sorry my English aren't good enough), but I tried one of the solutions given in that post and resolved the problem... so now it works, idk how but thanks :)