# How do I use .env and ormconfig.ts to connect to my database?

Tags: nestjs, typeorm

I am using NestJS and TypeORM and want to connect to my postgres database. But I am getting all kinds of errors. I am pretty sure it has to do with the ormconfig.ts and the entities in there. This is the file right now:

```
require('dotenv').config();

module.exports = {
    host: process.env.DB_HOST,
    type: 'postgres',
    port: process.env.DB_PORT,
    username: process.env.DB_USER,
    password: process.env.DB_PASS,
    database: process.env.DB_NAME,
    synchronize: true,
    entities: [__dirname + '/../**/*.entity.{js,ts}'],
};
```

and I am getting `SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module` Error in my Entity File that looks like this:

```
import { BaseEntity, Column, Entity, PrimaryGeneratedColumn } from "typeorm";

@Entity()
export class Software extends BaseEntity {
    @PrimaryGeneratedColumn()
    id: number;

    @Column()
    name: string;

    @Column()
    description: string; 
}
```

**Fixes that I have tried:**

- Adding

```
{
  // ...
  "type": "module",
  // ...
}
```

to my package.json from this question ["Uncaught SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module" when importing ECMAScript 6](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58211880/uncaught-syntaxerror-cannot-use-import-statement-outside-a-module-when-import)
(then I get `Object.defineProperty(exports, "__esModule", { value: true }); ReferenceError: exports is not defined`)

- changing `entities: [__dirname + '/../**/*.entity.{js,ts}']` in the ormconfig.ts to `autoLoadEntities: true,`, but then I get `EntityMetadataNotFound: No metadata for "Software" was found.`
- not using the path, but instead do `entities: [Software]` in ormconfig.ts, but it doesnt like the import statement `SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module` in the ormconfig.ts

It seems like everytime I fix one error, there is another one right away. Does anyone have any ideas as to why it might not work?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [TypeORM Entity in NESTJS - Cannot use import statement outside a module](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59435293/typeorm-entity-in-nestjs-cannot-use-import-statement-outside-a-module)

Comment: No I tried nearly every answer. It wont let me do `entities: [join(__dirname, '**', '*.entity.{ts,js}')]` because it will give me `SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module` for the join import. I tried adding `"typeorm": "ts-node -r tsconfig-paths/register ./node_modules/typeorm/cli.js"` to the package.json, nothing seems to work sadly

Comment: The reason for the error is that the command is finding `ts` files when `node` needs `js` files to run. The information in the linked issue is valid and functional.