# NestJS SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module

Tags: node.js, typescript, nestjs, typeorm

I have an error while migrating this migration:

```
import { MigrationInterface, QueryRunner } from "typeorm";


export class addIdColumnToBidProductsProductTable1626803008084 implements MigrationInterface {

public async up(queryRunner: QueryRunner): Promise<void> {
    await queryRunner.query('ALTER TABLE `bid_products_product` ADD id INT PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT');
}

public async down(queryRunner: QueryRunner): Promise<void> {
    await queryRunner.query('ALTER TABLE `bid_products_product` DROP COLUMN `id`');
}

}
```

And this is my error:

```
> bid@0.0.1 migration:show
> typeorm migration:show

Error during migration show:
/home/antikon/Projects/bid/src/migrations/1626803008084-addIdColumnToBidProductsProductTable.ts:1
import { MigrationInterface, QueryRunner } from "typeorm";
^^^^^^

SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module
    at Object.compileFunction (node:vm:352:18)
    at wrapSafe (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1025:15)
    at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1059:27)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1124:10)
    at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:975:32)
    at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:816:12)
    at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:999:19)
    at require (node:internal/modules/cjs/helpers:93:18)
    at /home/antikon/Projects/bid/node_modules/typeorm/util/DirectoryExportedClassesLoader.js:42:39
    at Array.map (<anonymous>)
```

This is my typeorm connection:

```
TypeOrmModule.forRoot({
      type: 'mysql',
      host: 'localhost',
      port: 3306,
      username: 'root',
      password: 'grish2003',
      database: 'biddb',
      entities: [User, Bid, Product, Bid_Product, Bet],
      synchronize: true,
      migrations: [
        join(__dirname, 'migrations/*{.ts}')
      ]
    })
```

This in a tsconfig.json file:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "module": "commonjs",
    "declaration": true,
    "removeComments": true,
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "target": "es2017",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "outDir": "./dist",
    "baseUrl": "./",
    "incremental": true
  }
}
```

I wanted to add one column to the database through migration, but this error came out.I tried a lot of things but nothing came of it.
Please tell me why it gives this error. Thank you

Comment: Does [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59435293/typeorm-entity-in-nestjs-cannot-use-import-statement-outside-a-module) answer helps?

Comment: Point your migration path from

"join(__dirname, 'migrations/*{.ts}')"
->
"join(__dirname, '..', 'dist', 'migrations/*{.js}')"