# Base entity from outside of the module

Tags: typescript, nestjs, typeorm

## Background

I'm using:

- `"@nestjs/core": "^8.1.1"`
- `"@nestjs/typeorm": "^8.0.3"`

My project structure is as follows:

```
src
|- api
|  |- common
|  |  |- entities
|  |  |  |- base.entity.ts <- important
|  |  |- common.module.ts
|  |- Foo
|  |  |- entities
|  |  |  |- some.entity.ts <- important
|  |  |- foo.module.ts
|- common
|  |- database
|  |  |- config
|  |  |  |- typeorm.config.ts
|  |  |- database.module.ts
|- app.module.ts
```

The modules:

```
// src/api/common/common.module.ts

@Module({
  imports: [TypeOrmModule.forFeature([Base])],
})
export class CommonModule {}
```

```
// src/api/foo/foo.module.ts

@Module({
  imports: [TypeOrmModule.forFeature([FoosRepository])],
  controllers: [FoosController],
  providers: [FoosService],
})
export class FooModule {}
```

All modules are imported in the `app.module.ts` as following:

```
// src/app.module.ts

@Module({
  imports: [
    ConfigModule.forRoot({ isGlobal: true }),
    DatabaseModule,
    CommonModule,
    FooModule,
  ],
})
export class AppModule {}
```

My TypeORM configuration looks like this:

```
// src/common/database/config/typeorm.config.ts

import { ConnectionOptions } from 'typeorm';

const Config: ConnectionOptions = {
  // ...
  entities: [__dirname + '/../src/**/*.entity{.js,.ts}'],

  // ...
  migrations: [__dirname + '/../migrations/**/*{.ts,.js}'],
  cli: {
    // Location of migration should be inside src folder
    // to be compiled into dist/ folder.
    migrationsDir: 'migrations',
  },
};

export default Config;
```

Entities:

```
// src/common/entities/base.entity.ts

import { CreateDateColumn, UpdateDateColumn } from 'typeorm';

export abstract class Base {
  @CreateDateColumn({
    type: 'timestamptz',
    default: () => 'CURRENT_TIMESTAMP(6)',
  })
  public createdAt: Date;

  @UpdateDateColumn({
    type: 'timestamptz',
    default: () => 'CURRENT_TIMESTAMP(6)',
    onUpdate: 'CURRENT_TIMESTAMP(6)',
  })
  public updatedAt: Date;
}
```

```
// src/api/foo/entities/foo.entity.ts

@Entity()
export class Foo extends Base {}
```

## Goal

I want to use `base` entity in `some` entity. The `base` is an abstract Entity that is 1:1 copy of the example from the [TypeORM docs](https://orkhan.gitbook.io/typeorm/docs/entity-inheritance).

## Problem

I get this error when running `npm run start:dev` command:

```
[Nest] 37068  - 02/27/2022, 6:18:22 PM   ERROR [TypeOrmModule] Unable to connect to the database. Retrying (1)...
/Users/XX/Workspace/project/src/api/common/entities/base.entity.ts:1
import { CreateDateColumn, UpdateDateColumn } from 'typeorm';
^^^^^^
```

I looked through similar issues however my `dist` folder contains only `main.js`, no entity files at all (which was suggested for example here: [TypeORM Entity in NESTJS - Cannot use import statement outside a module](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59435293/typeorm-entity-in-nestjs-cannot-use-import-statement-outside-a-module)