# How to run migration generate with TypeORM

Tags: mysql, node.js, express, migration, typeorm

I have an `express` app with `"typeorm": "^0.3.16",` . I used the data source configuration and now I want to generate migrations for the entities I've provided in data source :

db.ts

```
import { DataSource } from "typeorm";

import { Brand } from "@entity/brand.entity";

export const dataSource = new DataSource({
  type: "mysql",
  host: process.env.DB_HOST,
  port: Number(process.env.DB_PORT),
  database: process.env.DB,
  username: process.env.DB_USERNAME,
  password: process.env.DB_PASSWORD,
  logging: false,
  synchronize: false,
  migrations: ["../migration/**/*.ts"],
  migrationsRun: true,
  entities: [Brand],
});
```

And this is the command I run trying to generate migrations for the `Brand` entity :

```
"migration:generate": "typeorm migration:generate PostRefactoring -d src/config/db.ts"
```

But it gives me error :

```
Error during migration generation:
Error: Unable to open file: "/Users/mehdi/Desktop/zhivarteb-backend/src/config/db.js". Cannot use import statement outside a module
```

How can I generate typeorm migrations based on data source config file for provided entities in node js express ?

Comment: The error you're facing is perhaps related to `type` field in `package.json`. Try to add `type: 'module'` to `package.json`. However I'm afraid that running migrations is not related to the error you get.

Comment: @EmadMamaghani I tried and still getting this error .

Comment: Check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59435293/typeorm-entity-in-nestjs-cannot-use-import-statement-outside-a-module