# typeorm/Nest.js entities not loading

Tags: typescript, nestjs, typeorm

So It has been a little while since I've done this set up and looking for some help.
Now I know my data base connection works as the cache table will show up.

How ever I created 1 entity named Post to test the connection before i continue development.

post.entity.ts

```
import { Column, CreateDateColumn, Entity, PrimaryGeneratedColumn, UpdateDateColumn } from "typeorm";

@Entity()
export class Post {

  @PrimaryGeneratedColumn()
  id: number

  @Column()
  title: string

  @Column()
  content: string

  @Column()
  slug: string

  @Column()
  image_url: string

  @UpdateDateColumn({ type: "timestamp"})
  updated_at: Date

  @CreateDateColumn({ type: "timestamp"})
  created_at: Date
}
```

I have then added typeOrmModule for feature

post.module.ts

```
import { Module } from "@nestjs/common";
import { PostService } from './post.service';
import { PostController } from './post.controller';
import { TypeOrmModule } from "@nestjs/typeorm";
import { Post } from "./entities/post.entity";

@Module({
  imports: [
    TypeOrmModule.forFeature([
      Post
    ])
  ],
  controllers: [PostController],
  providers: [PostService],
})
export class PostModule {}
```

My type orm setup is done in my app module

```
import { Module } from '@nestjs/common';
import { AppController } from './app.controller';
import { AppService } from './app.service';
import { ConfigModule, ConfigService } from "@nestjs/config";
import { TypeOrmModule } from "@nestjs/typeorm";
import('reflect-metadata')

let envFilePath: string;
if (process.env.NODE_ENV === 'development') {
  envFilePath = '.env.development';
} else if (process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production') {
  envFilePath = '.env.production';
}

@Module({
  imports: [
    ConfigModule.forRoot({ isGlobal: true, envFilePath: envFilePath, }),
    TypeOrmModule.forRootAsync({
        imports: [ConfigModule],
        useFactory: async (configService: ConfigService) => ({
          type: 'mysql',
          host: configService.getOrThrow('MYSQL_HOST'),
          port: configService.getOrThrow('MYSQL_PORT'),
          username: configService.getOrThrow('MYSQL_USER'),
          password: configService.getOrThrow('MYSQL_PASSWORD'),
          database: configService.getOrThrow('MYSQL_DATABASE'),
          autoLoadEntities: true,
          synchronize: configService.getOrThrow('NODE_ENV') === 'development',
          cache: {
            type: 'database',
            duration: 30000,
            tableName: 'Helix-Data-Cache',
          },
          logging: true,
          metadataTableName: 'Helix-Metadata',
          migrationsTableName: 'Helix-Migrations',
        }),
        inject: [ConfigService]
      }
    )
  ],
  controllers: [
    AppController
  ],
  providers: [
    AppService
  ],
})
export class AppModule {}
```

Now I am not sure I did anything wrong and I can provide the logs for it though I have it running in a monorepo.

Comment: What exactly is not working? Can you give an example of what you do, what you expect to happen, and what happens instead?

Comment: So with th syncronize on it should create the table for post, However it does not create the table. But it creates the cache table.

This has me at a loss.

Comment: going off of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59435293/typeorm-entity-in-nestjs-cannot-use-import-statement-outside-a-module?rq=2 Seemed to get the table to create though

`entities: [join(__dirname, '**', '*.entity.{ts,js}')]`

addint that to the configuration seemed to fix it

Comment: Were you sure to include the PostModule in your app somewhere as well?

Comment: That Was My problem thank you for the help

Comment: No problem! Glad to help - btw, you can also add the entities directly instead of scanning a directory, if you want to control which are included, e.g. "entities: Post".

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/255352/discussion-between-tim-pierce-and-sebastiank).