nestjs an typeorm:Cannot use import statement outside a module
import {
  Entity,
  Column,
  UpdateDateColumn,
  PrimaryGeneratedColumn,
  CreateDateColumn,
} from 'typeorm';

export enum UserStatus {
  disabled = 0,
  enabled = 1,
}

@Entity()
export class User {
  @PrimaryGeneratedColumn() // 自增主键
  id?: number;

  @Column({ default: null }) // 普通类型
  name: string;

  @Column({ default: null })
  username: string;

  @Column({ default: null })
  email: string;

  @Column({ default: null })
  avatar?: string;

  @Column({ default: null })
  mobile?: string;

  @Column({ default: null })
  enName?: string;

  @Column({ default: null })
  departmentName?: string;

  @Column({ default: null })
  departmentId?: number;

  @Column({ default: UserStatus.enabled })
  status?: UserStatus;

  @UpdateDateColumn()
  updateTime?: string;

  @CreateDateColumn()
  createTime?: string;
}

import {
^^^^^^
SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module
at internalCompileFunction (node:internal/vm:73:18)
at wrapSafe (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1178:20)
at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1220:27)
at Object.Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1310:10)
at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1119:32)
at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:960:12)
at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1143:19)
at require (node:internal/modules/cjs/helpers:121:18)
at tryToRequire (E:\project\low-code-study\node_modules.pnpm\typeorm@0.3.20_mysql2@3.10.2_ts-node@10.9.2\src\util\ImportUtils.ts:21:17)
at importOrRequireFile (E:\project\low-code-study\node_modules.pnpm\typeorm@0.3.20_mysql2@3.10.2_ts-node@10.9.2\src\util\ImportUtils.ts:35:25)
I hope to solve this problem

Check this post that have a similar error:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59435293/typeorm-entity-in-nestjs-cannot-use-import-statement-outside-a-module?rq=2
